# How initialize array in typescript?

Tags: class, typescript, syntax

I'm using `InMemoryDbService` in Angular app. Some field of `model` is custom type.

The following field is array of classes:

```
public FlightQuotes: CFlightClassQuote[];
```

The following is initialization of this field:

```
const cf = new Array<CFlightClassQuote>();
cf[0] = new CFlightClassQuote();
cf[0].Class = 'A';
cf[0].ClassName = 'B';
cf[0].FreeBack = 2;
cf[0].FreeDirect = 5;
cf[1] = new CFlightClassQuote();
cf[1].Class = 'C';
cf[1].ClassName = 'D';
cf[1].FreeBack = 3;
cf[1].FreeDirect = 6;
......
......
const model = new MyModel();
model.FlightQuotes = cf;
```

Before asking this question i was search but without result. I'm not familiar with typescript syntax. 
Can i write shortly initialization of this array? Maybe something like in this:

```
model.FlightQuotes = [new CFlightClassQuote{Class = 'A'}, new CFlightClassQuote {Class = 'B'}];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For short initialisation of an array filled with typed objects you can use `Object.assign`:

```
model.FlightQuotes = [
    Object.assign(new CFlightClassQuote(), {
        'Class': 'A',
        ClassName: 'B'
    }),    
    Object.assign(new CFlightClassQuote(), {
        'Class': 'C',
        ClassName: 'D'
    }),
];
```

Answer (score 1):

TypeScript doesn't have the style of initialization you have shown in your question (i.e. the C# style initializer).

You can either create a new one using a constructor:

```
model.FlightQuotes = [
    new CFlightClassQuote('A'),
    new CFlightClassQuote('B')
 ];
```

Or if `CFlightClassQuote` is just a structure with no behaviour you can use the below (you have to supply all members) - this won't work if your class has methods etc, but works for interfaces / structures:

```
model.FlightQuotes = [
    { Class: 'A' },
    { Class: 'B' },
 ];
```

Or you could create a static mapper method that takes in the members, creates a new instance, and maps the properties - so at least you don't have to repeat that mapping:

```
model.FlightQuotes = [
    CFlightClassQuote.FromObject({ Class: 'A' }),
    CFlightClassQuote.FromObject({ Class: 'B' }),
 ];
```

Answer (score 0):

An other solution:

```
model.FlightQuotes = [{
        Class: 'A',
        ClassName: 'B'
    } as CFlightClassQuote,    
    {
        Class: 'C',
        ClassName: 'D'
    } as CFlightClassQuote),
];
```